# ccTouchBegin touch points are not being properly read

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

I made this ccTouchBegin method :

```
- (BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {



    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

    CGPoint pos = [self getChildByTag:1].position;


    CGSize size = [self getChildByTag:1].contentSize;
    float padding = 3;
    float w = size.width+padding*2;
    float h = size.height+padding*2;

    // first row
    CGRect rect1 = CGRectMake(pos.x-w/2, pos.y-h/2, w/3, h/3);
    CGRect rect2 = CGRectMake(pos.x-(w*(2/3)/2), pos.y-h/2, w/3, h/3);
    CGRect rect3 = CGRectMake(pos.x+(w*(2/3)/2), pos.y-h/2, w/3, h/3);
    //second row
    CGRect rect4 = CGRectMake(pos.x-w/2, pos.y-(h*(2/3)/2), w/3, h/3);
    CGRect rect5 = CGRectMake(pos.x-(w*(2/3)/2), pos.y-(h*(2/3)/2), w/3, h/3);
    CGRect rect6 = CGRectMake(pos.x+(w*(2/3)/2), pos.y-(h*(2/3)/2), w/3, h/3);
    //third  row
    CGRect rect7 = CGRectMake(pos.x-w/2, pos.y+(h*(2/3)/2), w/3, h/3);
    CGRect rect8 = CGRectMake(pos.x-w/2, pos.y+(h*(2/3)/2), w/3, h/3);
    CGRect rect9 = CGRectMake(pos.x-w/2, pos.y+(h*(2/3)/2), w/3, h/3);


    if (CGRectContainsPoint(rect1, location)) {
        NSLog(@"rect1");
    } else if (CGRectContainsPoint(rect2, location)) {
        NSLog(@"rect2");
    } else if (CGRectContainsPoint(rect3, location)) {
        NSLog(@"rect3");
    } else if (CGRectContainsPoint(rect4, location)) {
        NSLog(@"rect4");
    } else if (CGRectContainsPoint(rect5, location)) {
        NSLog(@"rect5");
    } else if (CGRectContainsPoint(rect6, location)) {
        NSLog(@"rect6");
    } else if (CGRectContainsPoint(rect7, location)) {
        NSLog(@"rect7");
    } else if (CGRectContainsPoint(rect8, location)) {
        NSLog(@"rect8");
    } else if (CGRectContainsPoint(rect9, location)) {
        NSLog(@"rect9");
    }

    return YES;
}
```

its simple, it takes the touch point, and then gets a child's contentsize and position and divides the place where the child is located to form a 3x3 table. but right now its not working and I am not getting any NSLogs even when I try touching the entire screen. any idea whats wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Learn how to set a breakpoint](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/10/xcode-4-debugging-crashcourse/). Breakpoints allow you to instantly test if a method or line of code is being executed or not.
2. The `ccTouchBegan` method isn't called unless you use the [CCTargetedTouchHandler](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/cocos2d-iphone/html/interface_c_c_targeted_touch_handler.html) as the default handler for touches in your CCLayer. To do this, override registerWithTouchDispatcher in your CCLayer class but don't call the super implementation:

---

```
-(void) registerWithTouchDispatcher
{
  [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self 
                                                   priority:0
                                            swallowsTouches:NO];
}
```

You do not need to remove the delegate. The CCLayer class handles that for you.